# Combobox Option Value Has spaces How do i Call them through VBA from excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Sprint()
Dim IE As Object
Dim objelement As Object
Dim c As Integer
Dim LastRow, i, j As Integer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
  .Visible = True
  .navigate "http://xxx"
  'wait until first page loads
  Do Until .readyState = 4
    DoEvents
  Loop   
  On Error Resume Next    
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TestData1")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For j = 2 To LastRow      
i = 1    
    If IE.Document.all.Item(i).innertext = "ÔÍÑ (ãîñ. ïîøëèíà)" Then
     IE.Document.all.Item(i).Click
     End If  
IE.Visible = True 
While IE.Busy
DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
Wend
With IE.Document
  'text boxes
  IE.Document.getElementById("txtSubscriberId").Value = sht.Cells(j, 9)
  .all("txtSubscriberId").Value = sht.Cells(j, 9)
  .all("btnPermValidateAddr").Click
  .all("txtSubscriberId").Value = sht.Cells(j, 9)
```

'This piece is selected in web page drop down since option value has no 
     spaces
     `IE.Document.getElementById("ddlProdCd").Value = sht.Cells(j, 20)
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlProdCd").FireEvent ("onfocus")
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlProdCd").FireEvent ("onchange")
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlProdCd").FireEvent ("onmousewheel")`

'This piece is not selected in web page drop down since option value has
     spaces 
     `IE.Document.getElementById("ddlPlanDesc").Value = sht.Cells(j, 21)
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlPlanDesc").FireEvent ("onfocus")
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlPlanDesc").FireEvent ("onmousewheel")
     IE.Document.getElementById("ddlPlanDesc").FireEvent ("onchange")
     End With
        Set IE = Nothing
     Next j
     End With
     End Sub`

In short 21st column value is not selected in webpage but 20th value is selected since in webpage option value has no space for 20th column value but 21st Column has space in option value in webpage itself
Refer attached Image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwwKB.png

Comment: Step through the options until you find the option you want to select. Capture the index of the option. You can then use the index to select the value

Comment: This works when i  add a break point

Comment: @Zac so can i reference value of index from excel? Since option value will do not want to hardcode it

Comment: @Zac i do not want to hardcode it can i do it by referencing index with option value via excel

Comment: Yes you can reference the index of a dropdown from excel. There are plenty of examples of how to do that on the net. Unfortunately because I don't have access to the website, I cannot test the code

Comment: It works now added Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))